# With new gcc version getting "warning: bool comparision"

Tags: c

```
if (!TempMode == TEMP) {
//code
}
```

log:
: warning: comparison of constant '10' with boolean expression is always false [-Wbool-compare]
    if (!TEMPMode == TEMP){

Comment: `bool` is *always* (always!) 0 or 1, so it'll never equal 2, which is what gcc is  warning you about.

Comment: Maybe you want to replace it with `SimReleaseMode != RELEASE_MODE_MIXED`?

Comment: Steve, the assignment in this 'static SimReleaseModeT SimReleaseMode = MODE_UNDEFINED;', 'MODE_UNDEFINED' is first constant in enum                                                                                                                                                                                                        so,the variable 'SimReleaseMode' is assigned to '0' right? why it is treating it as bool?

Comment: Aren’t you glad the new compiler is pointing out a bug in your code.  It didn’t work properly before, but now you’ve been told that it’s wrong. Phew! One less bug for your customers to worry about.

Comment: @Johnney I think it's clear now, but the problem is not that `SimReleaseMode` or `MODE_UNDEFINED` is being treated as a bool.  The problem is that the subexpression `!SimReleaseMode` is a bool.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a problem with operator precedence.  The unary `!` is evaluated first, calculating the logical NOT of `SimReleaseMode`; this is a boolean quantity (with type `int`, though, because C) and then *that* is used as the left-hand operand of the comparison.  GCC knows that neither possible numeric value of a boolean quantity (0 or 1) can compare equal to `RELEASE_MODE_MIXED` (numeric value 2), so it warns you.

You probably meant to write

```
if (!(SimReleaseMode == RELEASE_MODE_MIXED))
```

or more idiomatically

```
if (SimReleaseMode != RELEASE_MODE_MIXED)
```